# Monitoring api with reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have a backend application built with node.js. Every time there is a change in the database I want to reflect it in my ReactJs interface. (Like listing products or updating posts). I use mongodb as database and mongoose as ORM. How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use something that's call WebHook. [Webhook Article](https://blog.bearer.sh/consuming-webhooks-with-node-js-and-express/)